# When do you use obj!.attr and obj?.attr?

Tags: swift, option-type

- If `obj` not exist `obj?` generate a `nil` so `obj?.attr` too.
- If `obj` is nil then `obj!.attr` crashes.

But if I am sure `obj` at that certain point of the code always exist, than for me it seems it is independent which one to use. Am I right? What coding styles do you use?

Comment: They're not the same.  `obj?.attr` always returns an optional which you then have to worry about unwrapping.  `obj!.attr` is only an optional if `attr` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my very own opinion, if you're really sure that *obj* exists, you can use ! or ? either. They produce the same effect on an existing object. The only issue is the compiler: sometimes it's fine to use ! instead of ?, sometimes not.

Anyway, if you want to read further on this, give a chance to the free book by Apple "[The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11)": these things are very well explained there!

Comment: They're not the same.  `obj?.attr` always returns an optional which you then have to worry about unwrapping.  `obj!.attr` is only an optional if `attr` is.

Comment: @vacawama: I know, but this is not the question. If you're sure that obj exists, the compiler will let you use either ? or  ! without any difference.

Comment: Take a look at my example. There is a difference, even when `obj` exists.

Comment: The example you posted uses an Int: as they used to do in Objective-C, they're quite different from real objects. Anyway, in that specific case, you're right.

Comment: Any result returned from an optional chain will be an optional, not just `Int`s. If you know `obj` is not `nil` you'll save yourself the hassle of having to unwrap that optional later by force unwrapping the `obj` now and not creating an optional chain.

Answer (score 1):

If `obj` exists, `obj?.attr` returns an optional type even if `attr` is not an optional. On the other hand, `obj!.attr` will be whatever type `attr` is, so no additional unwrapping is needed if `attr` is a non-optional.

Consider this example:

```
class Person {
    var age = 37
}

var fred: Person? = Person()

let ageNextYear = fred?.age + 1  // error: value of optional type Int? not unwrapped
let ageLastYear = fred!.age - 1  // this works
```

Answer (score 0):

You use ? when you create a variable with out giving it a value, meaning it can exist and be used in an unitialized state. And as long as it is not initialized it has no type associated to it.

It has nothing do with the value being nil or not.

As Swift is type safe it requires all variables and constant to always hold a value by default, meaning they have a type. So defining something with ? or ! puts a wrapper around it.

```
enum Optional {
    case None
    case Some(T)
```

}

As you see it either has a type or not. Being nil (if possible for a type) or not has not much to do with it. But everything that does not have a type associated is usually nil.

When you then deal with the value of a variable that was declared as being optional, you need to unwrap it by using ! or else you would use the enumeration showed above.

Unwrapping means that you can assert that it does hold a value meaning it has a type. It takes it out of the enumeration and presents the value it has as a type.

Regarding coding style you usually only need to declare something as ? when you work with C or Objective-C APIs. In pure Swift you will usually not declare something as being optional.

You might need to use ! even in pure swift when something might not be defined. For example you have multi-dimensional array that were initialized as being empty. This is because of how Swift currently handle true multi-dimensional objects where the higher dimensions are implicit optionals.

TL;DR: Don't use ? at all unless you are forced to when dealing with C/Obj-C APIs. When using a value of a variable declared with ? always use ! to refer to the value and never ?.

Some links that explains what happens in more detail:

http://www.drewag.me/posts/what-is-an-optional-in-swift

http://www.drewag.me/posts/uses-for-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals-in-swift